# Can't bind inherited property (Xamarin Cross-Platform app)

Tags: c#, xamarin, inheritance, binding

I am trying to build a xamarin cross platform app, I am trying to use a List View control, but I can’t bind a public inherited property from a class. I get this console message when running the app.

[This is the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaPUE.png)

The class that contains the property is called Comida, which inherits from Producto class. Here are the class declarations for both Comida and Producto.This is the base class.

```
    public class Producto
{

    public String nombre { get; set; }
    public int precio { get; set; }
    public String usuario;
    public String descripcion="";


    public Producto(String nombre, int precio, String usuario)
    {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }


}
```

This is the inheriting one.

```
    public class Comida:Producto
{

    public static readonly String SALADO = "S";
    public static readonly String DULCE = "D";
    public String tipo;


    public Comida(String nombre, int precio, String usuario, String tipo): base(nombre,precio,usuario)
    {
        this.tipo = tipo;

    }


}
```

Comment: please do NOT post code and errors as images

Comment: @Jason Hi, I have replaced code images for actual code, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was resolved by adding the required properties as automatic properties with get and set.